# Laravel 5 custom named routes in resource controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I pass in my own extra named routes for a resource controller?

I have:

```
Route::resource('logistics', 'LogisticsController', ['names' => [
    'index-inbound' => 'logistics.indexInbound'
]]);
```

But this does not work.

Comment: Man, I don't know if that's possible, I've had to do it just creating a different route: Documentation doesn't talk about that besides the basics.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really add additional routes to a resource route. However, you can add any other routes you want and point them to the same controller:

```
Route::get('logistics/inbound', ['name' => 'logistics.index-inbound', 'uses' => 'LogistictsController@indexInbound']);
Route::resource('logistics', 'LogisticsController');
```

Just make sure that you register your custom routes *before* the resource route as otherwise they might get overridden.